# ASP.NET MVC CAPTCHA implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, captcha

I am attempting to implement a Captcha on a partial view of a page in my application.  I have the captcha being refrenced through web.config as a control.  I have used the GenericHandler and Class file from this forum post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1871186.aspx/1

How can I reference the user's input if i am using a simple input tag?  Should I use an HtmlHelper instead?

```
           <div class="captcha">
                <rhcap:Captcha ID="Captcha1" runat="server"></rhcap:Captcha>
                <input type="text" id="UserCaptchaText"><input/>
                <%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.UserCaptcha) %>
            </div>

            <%if(Captcha1.Text != /* How can get the users input here?*/ ) {
                  //display error

            }else{
                   //proceed
            }%>
```

Comment: NuGet **Google reCAPTCHA V2** for MVC 4 and 5

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)
- [Demo And Document](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use NuGet and install Recaptcha for .NET (supports MVC as well)

http://nuget.org/packages/RecaptchaNet/

Documentation is on the site:

http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com/

There are other captchas:

http://captchamvc.codeplex.com/

**EDIT**:

This project has moved to GitHub 
https://github.com/tanveery/recaptcha-net

Comment: my higher up does not like ReCaptcha. how can i convince him that it is the best choice? it took me less than 5 minutes to implement ReCaptcha...

Comment: yes. they think that the built in captcha from Microsoft will be just as easy. any estimate on how long it takes to use the built in captcha? i cant find much documentation on it, at least not for MVC 4..

Comment: @user1977591 - There is no built-in captcha in MVC.  I don't know of any built-in captcha in any Microsoft asp.net library, what are you referring to?

Comment: @user1977591 - Maybe they're talking about the WebHelpers library, but WebHelpers is not compatible with MVC, as it says on the NuGet page http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers/

Comment: Wow, thank you for this information.  They were convinced that MVC 4 comes with built in captch.  I had found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514(v=vs.108).aspx  if you scroll to validation it says something about a captcha.

Comment: They are also worried about the security of having ReCaptcha's dll in our project.  They believe that ReCaptcha could/would have access to certain things within our application.

Comment: @user1977591 - Well, it's wise to be cautious about code you get on the internet, but this is pretty well used code, and the source is available to browse.  You can see that this isn't the case.  That link to Captha on the link you provided is just a link to a blog post that describes how to create your own captcha library.

Answer (score 10):

NuGet **Google reCAPTCHA V2** for MVC 4 and 5

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)
- [Demo And Document](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

**Web.config** File in the appSettings section of your web.config file, add the keys as follows:

```
<appSettings>
   <add name="reCaptchaPublicKey" value="Your site key" />
   <add name="reCaptchaPrivateKey" value="Your secret key" />
</appSettings>
```

**Add Recaptcha in your view.**

```
@using reCAPTCHA.MVC
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Recaptcha()
    @Html.ValidationMessage("ReCaptcha")
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

**Verifying the user's response.**

```
[HttpPost]
[CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult Index(RegisterModel registerModel, bool captchaValid)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
    return View(registerModel);
}
```

EDIT:

You should also add this in your head tag or you might see improper captcha

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, it looks like you are mixing standard ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC. If you want to do MVC, the standard way to do it is the `Html.TextBoxFor()` type of stuff, and then you handle the value of that in a controller action method rather than write something inline in the page. So you have something like this:

```
Page.aspx
<rhcap:Captcha ID="Captcha1" runat="server"></rhcap:Captcha>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserCaptcha) %>
```

and then in:

```
SomeController.cs

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Page()
{
    // generate captcha code here
    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["Captcha"] = captchaValue;
    return View(new PageViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Page(PageViewModel model)
{
    if (model.UserCaptcha == ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["Captcha"])
    {
        // do valid captcha stuff
    }
}
```

To take this to the next level would be to implement it in a `FilterAttribute`. But this should work for most uses.

Comment: One captcha value per session? What if you have multiple captchas on different sites?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Google reCAPTCHA, is the best and easy to implement plus it comes with the trust of Google.

Very very effective and easy to implement.

Read this article written by me on [implementing Google reCAPTCHA in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3298/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-in-aspnet-mvc)

Thanks